# How was Erica able to open the door without a key card?

Tags: stranger-things

In episode 5 of Stranger Things season 3, a conversation between Steve and Robin when they are stuck in the elevator goes like this:

> Steve: They're buttons. They have to do something.
>   Robin: Yeah, if we had a keycard.

But just in the previous episode, Erica opened the door using one of those same buttons. How was that possible without a keycard?

Comment: The elevator was at the mall loading dock when she opened it, so it was probably already unlocked, maybe from the outside guard's keycard, or just by being docked at the surface